# RxJs: Map to anonymous type object

Tags: rxjs

I've created this `Observable`:

```
private accounts$: Observable<{type: string, alias: string}>;
```

I need to map an `Array<Account>` to an stream of `{type, alias}` object. Up to now, I've tried this:

```
this.accounts$ = this.store$
  .select(fromRoot.getDBoxAccountEntities)
  .flatMap(accounts => accounts.map(account => {type: 'dbox', alias: account.dboxAccount}))
  ...
```

However I'm getting compilation error messages.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are returning an object from your arrow function but the brackets suggest function body. You need `()` around your returned object:

`.flatMap(accounts => accounts.map(account => ({type: 'dbox', alias: account.dboxAccount})))`